# Is passing EventEmitter to an @Input an acceptable way to pass an event from parent to child?

Tags: angular

I'm feeling that it's a code smell and means that the code should be refactored but I'm not experienced enough with Angular to make the call.

Here's a quick example to show what I mean

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hctcn5

Comment: It is a pattern that I have never seen before, I would have avoided it if possible. It is probably a better way to achieve what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're mixing Inputs and Event emitters. When the components have parent-child relationship, you could directly bind the parent member variables to child component inputs.

parent.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
  `
  <my-app-child-one [buttonClick]="onSave"></my-app-child-one>\
  <my-app-child-two [buttonClick]="onSave"></my-app-child-two>\
  <button (click)="onSave=true">save</button>\
  <button (click)="onSave=false">unsave</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  onSave: boolean = false;
}
```

child-one.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-child-one',
  template: 
  '<p>Child 1 input: {{ buttonClick }}</p>',
})
export class ChildOneComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input()
  buttonClick: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

child-two.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-child-two',
  template: 
  '<p>Child 2 input: {{ buttonClick }}</p>',
})
export class ChildTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  buttonClick: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rphu5).

Also if you wish have a stream of data consider using RxJS observables like [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject), [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject), or [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject). [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64) is an Angular specific implementation of RxJS `Subject` that is better used with [`Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) decorator to emit custom events from components.

#### Update

There are multiple ways to pass data between components. If you wish to have a stream of data rather than a single value, you could look into above mentioned observables and singleton services.

On the other hand, you could bind the input to a setter to react to changes in input variables.

parent.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
  `
  <my-app-child-one [onSave]="onSave"></my-app-child-one>\
  <my-app-child-two [onSave]="onSave"></my-app-child-two>\
  <button (click)="onSave=true">save</button>\
  <button (click)="onSave=false">unsave</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  onSave: boolean = false;
}
```

child-one.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-child-one',
  template: 
  '<p>Child 1 input: {{ buttonClick }}</p>',
})
export class ChildOneComponent implements OnInit  {
  buttonClick: boolean;

  @Input()
  set onSave(value: boolean) {
    // do something
    this.buttonClick = value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

child-two.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-child-two',
  template: 
  '<p>Child 2 input: {{ buttonClick }}</p>',
})
export class ChildTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  buttonClick: boolean;

  @Input()
  set onSave(value: boolean) {
    // do something
    this.buttonClick = value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngq2kd)

Comment: Guess I've oversimplified the example. In our app the onSave inside children components does some data validation on the data that is input by the users in the rather large child component.